# Generating functions in simplified form

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions

If you have the generating function:
$$(1+x+x^2+\dotso)$$
is the same as
$$\frac{1}{(1-x)}$$

If you have the generating function (evens):
$$(1+x^2+x^4+x^6+\dotso)$$
is the same as 
$$\frac{1}{(1-x^2)}$$

However, what happens when you have the generating function for odds?

i.e. $(x+x^3+x^5+x^7+\dotso)$

What does this "convert" to?

Comment: hint: $(x+x^3+x^5+x^7+\dotso)= x(1+x^2+x^4+x^6+\dotso)$

Comment: @David’s approach it by far the easiest, but you could also note that $$x+x^3+x^5+\ldots=(1+x+x^2+x^3+\ldots)-(1+x^2+x^4+x^6+\ldots)\;,$$ which you know is $$\frac1{1-x}-\frac1{1-x^2}\;;$$ just do a bit of algebra to simplify this.

Comment: good point, Brian. the transformation you give is more potent for generalization e.g. to show $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac1{(2n-1)^2} = 3\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac1{(2n)^2}$

Answer (score 1):

Since 
$$x+x^3+x^5... = x(1+x^2+x^5+...)$$
and 
$$1+x^2+x^5+...=\frac{1}{1-x^2} \ ,$$
we have that
$$x+x^3+x^5... = x\left(\frac{1}{1-x^2}\right) =\frac{x}{1-x^2} \ .$$